# How "string-button" is implemented as UI control?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I like the tortoise svn 1.8 commit UI interface.

It can filter out need-committed files by clicking       the **'all', 'none',...,'deleted', 'modified'** buttons etc.  But these buttons have no rectangle borders, they are just strings, as Labels.

*I wonder if I can implement them with delphi, as I know tsvn is written in C++.*

Comment: Er, `TLabel` has `OnClick`

Comment: [TStaticText](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TStaticText) can be a good alternative for `TLabel`.

Answer (score 5):

You can just use a TLabel and OnClick event.
You can also implement a style with OnMouseEnter and revert it with OnMouseLeave.

Comment: And to make it more clear to your users, change the cursor to `crHandPoint`

Answer (score 0):

The `TSpeedButton` with the property `Flat` set to true results in a label-like appearance. However, when you hover over it displays as a button which I think results in good user experience, i.e. showing that it is clickable.